# How to reset GridFilter in extjs

Tags: extjs

This is what I am doing:

```
this.TabPanel.Grid.getStore().clearFilter (false);
alert(this.TabPanel.Grid.getStore().isFiltered());
```

and the alert shows: false. When I go on the page, I see that the filter is still selected(checked) and the results are also fitlered. What I am missing?

EDIT:Can I get a handle to the gridfilter object through my store? If yes, I can call the `gridfilter.clearFilters().`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How is that code running? Can you post a more complete example? If you have some component that is a user is using to set the filter(like some check box or something), you will still need to clear that manually as well.

Comment: this.TabPanel.Grid.getStore().clearFilter (false); This will not clear the existing filter(s)??

Comment: clearFilter has nothing to do with a checkbox or any controls at all. If you are enabling the filter by a checkbox, and your call clearFilter on the store that does nothing to clear the checkbox.

Comment: Thanks. Does my EDIT help to give any more info on the problem?

Comment: grid.Filters.ClearFilters() solves the prob for now. Thank you.